# Akka DeadLetter monitor not receiving messages sent by unhandled()

Tags: akka

I have the following actor setup:

```
public class Master extends AbstractActor {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(Init.class, init -> {
          log.info("Master received an Init, creating DLW and subscribing it.");
          ActorRef deadLetterWatcher = context().actorOf(Props.create(DeadLetterWatcher.class),
            "DLW");

          context().system().eventStream().subscribe(deadLetterWatcher, DeadLetterWatcher.class);
          log.info("Master finished initializing.");
        })
        .matchAny(message -> {
          log.info("Found a {} that Master can't handle.",
              message.getClass().getName());
          unhandled(message);
        }).build();
  }
}

public class DeadLetterWatcher extends AbstractActor {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .matchAny(message -> {
        log.info("Got a dead letter!")
      }).build();
  }
}
```

At startup the `Master` actor is created and is sent an `Init` message, and sure enough, I *do* see the following log output:

```
Master received an Init, creating DLW and subscribing it.
Master finished initializing.
```

However shortly after this, `Master` is sent a `Fizzbuzz` message, and I see this in the logs:

```
Found a com.me.myapp.Fizzbuzz that Master can't handle.
```

But then I *don't* see the `DeadLetterWatcher` log "*Got a dead letter!*", which tells me I have something wired incorrectly. Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in `akka.actor.UnhandledMessage.class`, instead of `DeadLetterWatcher.class`, to the `subscribe()` method:

```
context().system().eventStream().subscribe(deadLetterWatcher, akka.actor.UnhandledMessage.class);
```

Note that [unhandled messages](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#defining-an-actor-class) are not the same thing as dead letters. For the former, an actor "must provide a pattern match for all messages that it can accept, and if you want to be able to handle unknown messages, then you need to have a default case." Your `Master` actor handles only `Init` messages; all other messages that it receives are considered "unhandled" and trigger the publication of an `akka.actor.UnhandledMessage` to the `EventStream`. You're explicitly calling the `unhandled` method for non-`Init` messages, but [`unhandled` would be called by default](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actor-api) if you didn't have the fallback `case` clause. Also note that you can [log unhandled messages](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/logging.html#auxiliary-logging-options) via the configuration, without the need of a "monitor" actor:

```
akka {
  actor {
    debug {
      # enable DEBUG logging of unhandled messages
      unhandled = on
    }
  }
}
```

[Dead letters](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#dead-letters), on the other hand, are messages that cannot be delivered, such as messages that are sent to a stopped actor, and they also trigger the [publication of messages to the `EventStream`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/event-bus.html#dead-letters).

Since unhandled messages are different from dead letters, your `DeadLetterWatcher` is misnamed and should probably be named something like `UnhandledMessageWatcher`. That being said, if your goal is only to log unhandled messages, then the simplest approach is to do so with the logging configuration mentioned above.

Comment: `UnhandledMessage` or `DeadLetter` though?!